# How long does it take for a Sagemaker endpoint configuration's training job to finish so you can create the endpoint?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm new to Sagemaker but have been waiting a few hours for a Sagemaker training job to complete so that I can create the endpoint... The Sagemaker console shows a Create endpoint button, but when I press it, it doesn't work. The end point configuration still has a spinning icon for "Training job"

How long does it typically take for a Sagemaker endpoint to spin up?

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker endpoint creation time depends on model size, machine type and serving stack complexity. Yet given upload bandwidth from S3 to EC2 and usual ML model artifact size, (Kb to single-digit Gb) **in practice I found that it rarely takes more than 10min to instantiate a SageMaker endpoint**.

The hours-long task your are waiting for to complete is likely the model training, which could take as little as a fraction of second up to several days (Google's Neural Machine Translation model, [GNMT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.08144.pdf) from Wu et al, reports a 6-day training). The [SageMaker documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sagemaker.html) mentions that max training time is 5 days though. You can look at Cloudwatch logs to confirm status of your training task